# Laravel form collective checkbox

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

so how can I make a default checked/unchecked checkbox, with values from the data base? I'm using Form model from laravel collective and my checkbox field is this:

```
Form::model($role, ['route' => ['the_route', $role->slug], 'method' => 'patch'])

    @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
        Form::checkbox('permission['.$permission->slug.']', 'true', null, ['class' => 'square'])
    @endforeach

Form::close()
```

The thing is that `$role->permissions` returns an array like this:

```
array:3 [
  "dashboard.view" => "false"
  "user.view" => "true"
  "user.edit" => "false"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter is a boolean `$checked`, so you may write it like this:

```
Form::model($role, ['route' => ['the_route', $role->slug], 'method' => 'patch'])

    @foreach ($permissions as $slug => $value)
        Form::checkbox('permission['.$slug.']', 'true', (bool) $value, ['class' => 'square'])
    @endforeach

Form::close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Lavel Collective have one intriguing resource that is not documented, as least I never found it in any site. Name your checkbox with them same name that you gave for relation between your two models, like "permissions", and then Laravel Collective will check all input that are in that relation. In your specific case, $role->permission should return an model, not array, like normally is in any Laravel app.

Check an sample code:

```
{!! Form::model($role, ['route' => ['roles.update',  $user->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}

    <div class="row form-group">

        @foreach($permissions as $permission)
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                {!! Form::checkbox('permissions[]', $permission->id) !!}
                {!! Form::label('permissions', $permission->name) !!}
            </div>
        @endforeach

    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

// Role model

```
class Role extends Model 
{

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'permission_role');
    }
}
```

// Permission model

```
class Permission extends Model
{

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'permission_role');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this saved me a lot of time.